# Creating a SCSS Compass-Style Mixin -> Animation

Tags: sass, compass-sass

At the moment, I am trying to de-clutter some CSS into SCSS (via Compass Style). This is what I mean:

```
-webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
-moz-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
-ms-animation: moveFromBottom 300ms ease;
```

------------>

I have done something similar with my transition for example:

Before:

```
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear;
```

After:

```
@include single-transition(all, 200ms, linear);
```

However my issue is that I cannot find a Compass Style support for this. How do you create this into a mixin, with "moveFromBottom" included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [compass-animation](https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation) plugin for Compass.

Comment: This plugin has moved into the compass core for 0.13 (currently in alpha). You can either install the plugin to use with 0.12.x, and upgrade later, or start using the pre-release compass gem with animations included. Either way, it's the same code.

Comment: I will look into the upgrade, I have no time to dabble (however much fun it is :)